# XNA Spritebatch Point Clamp Texture Render Glitch

Tags: xna, spritebatch

In XNA, I am rendering textures using the PointClamp sampler state, and I have a tilemap using a horizontally aligned spritesheet of various 8 x 8 tile images to render each tile. I am also using a transformation matrix to scale and move the camera. My problem is that at a scale of 1, my tilemap sprites draw correctly, but at a higher scale (2, 3, etc.), the tile images offset by one pixel every so often as I move the camera around. You can see the problem I am having in this screenshot:

[image]

Also, the small white lines that appear are not supposed to be there, and only show up when the images are drawing offset like this. Does anyone know how I can avoid the tiles being drawn like this?

I have a feeling that the white "dots" are from neighboring tile in the spritesheet. I could add a 1 pixel buffer between the tile images on the spritesheet, but I'm afraid that just may cause transparent lines to appear between tiles when this problem occurs.

Comment: Hm... assuming your scaling is correct, perhaps a value is being rounded improperly at some point, such that it rounds up by a pixel and out of the proper bounds. But, without posting any code it is hard to help much more.